# Java - Tomcat 6 - Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, environment-variables

I have two spring boot applications deployed on a tomcat6 server (Java 8) with the next META-INF/context.xml definition:

App1

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    
    <Context>
        <Environment name='application.properties' value='/etc/app1/ws/application.properties' type='java.lang.String'/>
        <Environment name='logging.config' value='/etc/app1/ws/logback.xml' type='java.lang.String'/>
    </Context>
```

App2

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Context>
        <Environment name='application.properties' value='/etc/app2/ws/application.properties' type='java.lang.String'/>
        <Environment name='logging.config' value='/etc/app2/ws/logback.xml' type='java.lang.String'/>
    </Context>
```

Both **application.properties** files has the key "**spring.datasource.url**".

One is for an AS400 database (**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://...**) and the other is for a SQLSERVER database (**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://...**)
The problem is, the **app1** (the one with the AS400 datasource) starts OK but when the **app2** (the one with the SQL server datasource) is starting, I get the error:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver**

but the app2 uses the SQL connection.

The app2 is using app1 context and wrong application.properties and I don't know why because I tried both applications on dev server and works fine. Now I'm promoting this to production but I have the problem only on the production tomcat.

I need to change some configuration in tomcat to force separated context environment variables by apps?

Comment: For both the apps you mentioned the same datasource **spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://...**. Shouldn't there be a different connection string for the app2 application.properties datasource URL? For a MS SQL Server, I would assume the URL starts with jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433; or something

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error on the question, the second connection string is like you described (edited on the question)

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the ClassNotFoundException? Can you do a project wide search within the app2 project for the string "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400:" to find that out?